# Debugging ASP.Net app - skipping lines and breakpoints not being hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am experiencing a very strange issue while debugging an ASP.Net application. It seems to happen to all functions inside a certain class. There are several issues which I suspect are all related:

- Breakpoints inside the functions are ignored but if I put a breakpoint *before* that function is called and then f11 to step in I can debug the function as normal.
- If I attach the debugger and then add a break point it will add it (although it will be ignored as above) as long as the code hasn't been executed. Once the function has been called if I try and add a break point visual studio gives an error "The following breakpoint cannot be set...The common language runtime was unable to set the break point.
- While debugging some of the lines seems to get skipped over completely. For example consider the function below:

  ```
  public GetCareersParametersByCriteriaResponse GetCareersParametersByCriteria(GetCareersParametersByCriteriaRequest request)
  {
      var response = new GetCareersParametersByCriteriaResponse {
         CareersParameters = new List<CareerParametersView>()
      };
      var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<CareerView>();

      if (!request.IncludeExcludeTop20Careers) {
         predicate = predicate.And(c => !c.ExcludeTop20);
      }
      predicate = predicate.And(c =>
                                c.EducationMinimumLevel <= request.MinimumEducationLevel &&
                                c.EducationMaximumLevel >= request.MaximumEducationLevel);
      var careerIds = _careerLibrary.Careers.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).Select(c => c.CareerId).Distinct();
      foreach (var careerId in careerIds) { 
          response.CareersParameters.Add(_careerLibrary.CareerParametersLookup[careerId]);
      }

      response.IsSuccess = true;

      return response;
  }
  ```

It seems to skip assigning to 'predicate' and the value shows as null. However the line later that adds the education min / max still executes but the value of predicate remains null. From there it skips straight *into* the foreach without assigning to careerIds and seemingly without calling move next on the iterator. As a result careerId is not assigned a value (so has 0) and throws an error because 0 is not a valid Id.

**Note:** Even though 0 is an invalid id and results in a 'given key not present in the dictionary' exception being thrown, the function continues executing and does the return. At that point the debugger disappears completely (doesn't return to calling function) and everything seems to lock (i.e. the page never loads etc) until I detach the debugger and it gives the yellow screen of death.

Thing I have already tried:

- Cleaning solution
- Rebuilding solution
- Manually deleting all dlls and pdb files in bin folder
- Restarting visual studio
- Rebooting
- Ensuring 'Optimize Code' is disabled
- Ensuring that multiple threads aren't calling the function at the same time
- Modifying the code file and making sure it picks up the changes to make sure it is running the most current version. It is. (also opended the Debug > Windows > Modules and checked the timestamp on the pdb - it's up to date)
- Deleting IIS copy of DLLs located at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Clearing Symbol Cache
- Complete reinstall of VS2012 and all plugins (e.g. resharper)

It seemed to start happening immediately after installing the VS2012 update 4 but I cannot find anything online regarding any problems like this after the update, and reinstalling VS did not help so this may be coincidence

**Update:** After getting a message while debugging that the source code was different to the dll at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files...(i.e. IIS copy of the code) I thought I might be on to something. However after deleting those it still made no difference at all, so adding that to the list of things I've tried

**Update 2:** Completely reinstalled VS2012 since I suspected the update might be at fault. However still no joy, same strange behaviour

**Update 3:** After further investigation I seem to get the same strange problems for all classes inside the same project / assembly (other projects in the solution are fine) this suggests a project level setting somewhere. Open to all suggestions :-)

**Update 4:** Tried Clearing Symbol Cache at Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols

**update 5:** Tried reinstalling VS2012 from scratch - still no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end a full reformat and reinstall was the only thing that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the `Modules` window `(Debug->Windows->Modules)` and have a look through the list of modules. You should see DLL files relating to your project. Now, the important thing is whether the `Symbol Status` columns says `Symbols Loaded`. If it does not, then have a look at the `Path` column, check whether that looks correct.

Comment: I have checked the modules window - shows all the relevant symbols are loaded and the timestamps correspond correctly to the last build time